# Android ,Interface ,new Instance

Tags: java, android, reflection

i have a problem with a newInstance call using Reflection in Android.

My Interface:

```
public interface IGiver {
    public int getNr();
}
```

My Class to call Reflection:

```
public class NrGiver implements IGiver {
    int i = 10;
    @Override
    public int getNr() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

The way i try to call getNr:

```
String packageName = "de.package";
String className = "de.package.NrGiver";

String apkName = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).sourceDir;
            PathClassLoader myClassLoader =
                new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(
                            apkName,
                        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
Class c =  Class.forName(className);
IGiver giver = (IGiver) c.newInstance();
```

The last line wont work it cause an Error and my App stops.
I know it fault of newInstance, but i want to work on the IGiver object.

Pls Help me.

My Solution:

Hey guys finally i got the chicken.

I found an other way. this time i also used newInstance, but this time its worked.
My solution:

```
Class c =  Class.forName(className);
Method methode = c.getDeclaredMethod("getNr");
Object i = methode.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[]{});
```

And this what i wanted to do.
I have an NrGiver.class somewhere on my Phone. And it implements the Interface IGiver. So it can be loaded into my App dynamically. I need the Integer from the class NrGiver. So i can make my code generic. I tried to Cast the Object to my Interface, but it failed.

So i found an other way to invoke the method of a class.

Thx for help

Comment: Interfaces can't have any instances, this is why it won't work

Comment: An error? What error, exactly? Use logcat.

Comment: @Egor i think its not an Interface. Its an Class NrGiver. IGiver is an interface.

Comment: Please, make your answer as a separate answer to your question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
String className = "de.package.NrGiver";//line 1
Class c =  Class.forName(className);//line 2
IGiver giver = (IGiver) c.newInstance();//line3
```

in **line 2** forName is trying to find a class but the String is representing a Interface, so the classLoader does not find the class and it throws an exception. adding on to it, in **line 3** you are trying to get an Instance of Interface which does't exist in the `java world`.. i mean to say Interfaces cannot be **instanciated** and they **do not have constructors.**.

Comment: How is this instantiating the interface?  `newInstance` is `de.package.NrGiver` and he is simply casting it AS an interface..

Comment: @Ryan.. i don't to what extent i'm right.. but read this..http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

Comment: line 2 is a class of NrGiver and it implements an Interface IGiver. After i load class NrGiver and try to create a new instance. but here the whole thing fails i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

not sure why is classloader used. if both IGiver and NrGiver are loaded:

```
Class k = NrGiver.class;
IGiver g = (IGiver)k.newInstance();
```

Comment: I want to build an app which can manage plugins. So I define the Interface IGiver and need to load the classes which ill add at a later time. So i need the cast to the IGiver Interface of an object NrGiver.